# Caused by: org.hibernate.MappingException: Could not determine type for:

Tags: java, spring-data-jpa, hibernate-mapping

My code have some problem about Hibernate mapping.
It told me that **Caused by: org.hibernate.MappingException: Could not determine type for:**
Here is CompanyEntity class

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "company", schema = "sit2job")
public class CompanyEntity {

    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE)
    private int companyId;
    private String address;
    private String contactPersonName;
    private String description;
    private String detail;
    private String email;
    private String faxNo;
    private String name;
    private String phoneNo;
    private String website;

    @OneToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="user_id")
    private UserEntity userId;

    public UserEntity getUserId() {
        return userId;
    }

    public void setUserId(UserEntity userId) {
        this.userId = userId;
    }

    @Id
    @Column(name = "company_id", nullable = false)
    public int getCompanyId() {
        return companyId;
    }

    public void setCompanyId(int companyId) {
        this.companyId = companyId;
    }

    @Basic
    @Column(name = "address", nullable = true, length = 500)
    public String getAddress() {
        return address;
    }

    public void setAddress(String address) {
        this.address = address;
    }

    @Basic
    @Column(name = "contact_person_name", nullable = true, length = 500)
    public String getContactPersonName() {
        return contactPersonName;
    }

    public void setContactPersonName(String contactPersonName) {
        this.contactPersonName = contactPersonName;
    }

    @Basic
    @Column(name = "description", nullable = true, length = 500)
    public String getDescription() {
        return description;
    }

    public void setDescription(String description) {
        this.description = description;
    }

    @Basic
    @Column(name = "detail", nullable = true, length = 500)
    public String getDetail() {
        return detail;
    }

    public void setDetail(String detail) {
        this.detail = detail;
    }

    @Basic
    @Column(name = "email", nullable = false, length = 50)
    public String getEmail() {
        return email;
    }

    public void setEmail(String email) {
        this.email = email;
    }

    @Basic
    @Column(name = "fax_no", nullable = true, length = 25)
    public String getFaxNo() {
        return faxNo;
    }

    public void setFaxNo(String faxNo) {
        this.faxNo = faxNo;
    }

    @Basic
    @Column(name = "name", nullable = false, length = 100)
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    @Basic
    @Column(name = "phone_no", nullable = false, length = 25)
    public String getPhoneNo() {
        return phoneNo;
    }

    public void setPhoneNo(String phoneNo) {
        this.phoneNo = phoneNo;
    }

    @Basic
    @Column(name = "website", nullable = true, length = 100)
    public String getWebsite() {
        return website;
    }

    public void setWebsite(String website) {
        this.website = website;
    }
```

and Here is UserEntity Class

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "user", schema = "sit2job")
public class UserEntity {
    private int userId;
    private String username;
    private String password;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="role_id")
    private RoleEntity roleId;

    @OneToOne(mappedBy = "userId", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @PrimaryKeyJoinColumn
    private CompanyEntity companyId;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE)
    @Column(name = "user_id", nullable = false)
    public int getUserId() {
        return userId;
    }

    public void setUserId(int userId) {
        this.userId = userId;
    }

    @Basic
    @Column(name = "username", nullable = false, length = 50)
    public String getUsername() {
        return username;
    }

    public void setUsername(String username) {
        this.username = username;
    }

    @Basic
    @Column(name = "password", nullable = false, length = 200)
    public String getPassword() {
        return password;
    }

    public void setPassword(String password) {
        this.password = password;
    }

    public RoleEntity getRoleId() {
        return roleId;
    }

    public void setRoleId(RoleEntity roleId) {
        this.roleId = roleId;
    }

    public CompanyEntity getCompanyId() {
        return companyId;
    }

    public void setCompanyId(CompanyEntity companyId) {
        this.companyId = companyId;
    }
```

These two classes located at different package
It's has an error

```
Error starting ApplicationContext. To display the conditions report re-run your application with 'debug' enabled.
2018-09-14 01:59:27.805 ERROR 16007 --- [           main] o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Application run failed

org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/orm/jpa/HibernateJpaConfiguration.class]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is javax.persistence.PersistenceException: [PersistenceUnit: default] Unable to build Hibernate SessionFactory; nested exception is org.hibernate.MappingException: Could not determine type for: com.sit.sit2job.Company.Entity.CompanyEntity, at table: user, for columns: [org.hibernate.mapping.Column(company_id)]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1708) ~[spring-beans-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:581) ~[spring-beans-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:503) ~[spring-beans-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:317) ~[spring-beans-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222) ~[spring-beans-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:315) ~[spring-beans-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:199) ~[spring-beans-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBean(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1089) ~[spring-context-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:859) ~[spring-context-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:550) ~[spring-context-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:140) ~[spring-boot-2.0.3.RELEASE.jar:2.0.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:759) [spring-boot-2.0.3.RELEASE.jar:2.0.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:395) [spring-boot-2.0.3.RELEASE.jar:2.0.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:327) [spring-boot-2.0.3.RELEASE.jar:2.0.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1255) [spring-boot-2.0.3.RELEASE.jar:2.0.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1243) [spring-boot-2.0.3.RELEASE.jar:2.0.3.RELEASE]
    at com.sit.sit2job.Sit2jobApplication.main(Sit2jobApplication.java:17) [classes/:na]
Caused by: javax.persistence.PersistenceException: [PersistenceUnit: default] Unable to build Hibernate SessionFactory; nested exception is org.hibernate.MappingException: Could not determine type for: com.sit.sit2job.Company.Entity.CompanyEntity, at table: user, for columns: [org.hibernate.mapping.Column(company_id)]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.buildNativeEntityManagerFactory(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:402) ~[spring-orm-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:377) ~[spring-orm-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:341) ~[spring-orm-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1767) ~[spring-beans-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1704) ~[spring-beans-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
    ... 16 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.hibernate.MappingException: Could not determine type for: com.sit.sit2job.Company.Entity.CompanyEntity, at table: user, for columns: [org.hibernate.mapping.Column(company_id)]
    at org.hibernate.mapping.SimpleValue.getType(SimpleValue.java:456) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.17.Final.jar:5.2.17.Final]
    at org.hibernate.mapping.SimpleValue.isValid(SimpleValue.java:423) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.17.Final.jar:5.2.17.Final]
    at org.hibernate.mapping.Property.isValid(Property.java:226) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.17.Final.jar:5.2.17.Final]
    at org.hibernate.mapping.PersistentClass.validate(PersistentClass.java:597) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.17.Final.jar:5.2.17.Final]
    at org.hibernate.mapping.RootClass.validate(RootClass.java:265) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.17.Final.jar:5.2.17.Final]
    at org.hibernate.boot.internal.MetadataImpl.validate(MetadataImpl.java:329) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.17.Final.jar:5.2.17.Final]
    at org.hibernate.boot.internal.SessionFactoryBuilderImpl.build(SessionFactoryBuilderImpl.java:461) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.17.Final.jar:5.2.17.Final]
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.build(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:892) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.17.Final.jar:5.2.17.Final]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.createContainerEntityManagerFactory(SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.java:57) ~[spring-orm-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.createNativeEntityManagerFactory(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:365) ~[spring-orm-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.buildNativeEntityManagerFactory(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:390) ~[spring-orm-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
    ... 20 common frames omitted
```

I want to know what is the cause of these problem. I have though the cause of problem is @OneToOne because @OneToMany or @ManyToOne have no any problem.

Comment: did you include in your persistence.xml <class>com.sit.sit2job.Company.Entity.CompanyEntity</class>

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you are mapping a `companyId` with a `userId` you also need to provide the name of the column like this: `@JoinColumn(name="company_id")`

So you maybe want something like this:

```
@OneToOne(mappedBy = "companyId", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
@PrimaryKeyJoinColumn
@JoinColumn(name="company_id")
private CompanyEntity companyId;
```